# How to specify to a resource folder which filter to use Maven?

Tags: java, maven, maven-resources-plugin

I have two configuration properties files and two `application Context xml files` , ones for test and others for development  and I have to specify which filter to use for each case .

I tried to do this but it's not working, it's select the last filter from the `pom.xml` ,so when i check the files `applicationContext.xml` in the folder `target/classes` and `/target/test-classes` I found the both files had the same values taken from the last filter declared on `pom.xml`

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>


    <filters>
        <filter>src/test/filters/filter.properties</filter>
        <filter>src/main/filters/filter.properties</filter>
    </filters>
```

so i wonder if there is a solution to specify for each case the appropriate filter to use ?

Answer (score 1):

You might use [profiles](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-maven-profiles.html).

Unfortunately `filters` aren't allowed inside `profile`, so you could use the following workaround:

Outside profiles write:

```
<filters>
    <filter>src/${switch}/filters/filter.properties</filter>
</filters>
```

In a main profile write:

```
<properties>
  <switch>main</switch>
</properties>
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

in a test profile write:

```
<properties>
  <switch>test</switch>
</properties>
<testResources>
    <testResource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
    </testResource>
</testResources>
```

Finally run:

```
mvn install -Pmain
```

or:

```
mvn install -Ptest
```